# Altering meta viewport tag

Tags: jquery, width, meta-tags, viewport

I need to alter the meta viewport tag dependent on the width of the visual viewport. I know HOW to do it, but it's not working. I think it's because the site is running that bit of JS too late for it to take effect. It may not be this, but this is my first thought.

In my application.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // If the screen width is 480 or less, then add a meta viewport tag
  // (so the default mobile display is used on iPads until that optimized view is added)
  if (window.innerWidth <= 480) { // This looks at the size of the visual viewport
    $('#viewport').attr('content', 'width=device-width');
  }

}
```

In my index.html:

```
<meta id="viewport" name='viewport'><!-- content attr is added via JS -->
```

Any ideas on how I can get that block to run as early as possible so it actually takes effect?

Comment: have you tried using `$('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=device-width');`, or are you sure this is not a selector issue?

Comment: I have figured out that it is not due to my original thought. It is due to the fact that window.innerWidth is returning 980 on my iPhone 4S when I expect it to be 480 or less (should be 320 in portrait). It seems like it's device pixels are being returned rather than CSS pixels like I need even though PPK here states http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html that window.innerWidth returns CSS pixels.

Any ideas how I can get it to return CSS pixels of the visual viewport rather than device pixels?

Comment: It's not because of what you think, it's a bug with the device, wrap the function in `setTimeout(theFunction, 200)`; let me know if that works.

Comment: Ok, I tried the following:

      function checkViewport() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 480) { // This looks at the size of the visual viewport
      $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">');
    }
  }

  setTimeout(checkViewport(), 200);

But no luck with that. Why is window.innerWidth returning the device pixels instead of css pixels?

Comment: it's an obscure bug. this needs to be executed after the dom is ready, so whatever you've written above would also need to be wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function(){})`. Also, it would be best to place this `<script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: But surely, everytime that function is run, window.innerWidth will ALWAYS report 980 on the iPhone 4 so that meta viewport tag will never get appended. I need to find out why window.innerWidth is returning 980 instead of 320.

Comment: Anyone have any more ideas to resolve this. Overall, I want the meta viewport tag to be added if the width of the visual viewport is 480 css pixels or less. Simple as that. Nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Sorry I can't help but just to let you know I am searching for exactly the same thing. For me this is so that the liquid/mobile layout only kicks in below a certain value. - otherwise the whole website is shrunk. I'm still wondering if its something to do with it not running quick enough so it gets the scale wrong.

Comment: I think this is one of those situations where this isn't a good way to achieve this. Unless the meta tag is there then iphone thinks its 980. Perhaps doing a sniff for iphone and only adding that tag would work but then some other devices might also need the tag

Comment: Nearly had this working using screen.width and device.pixel.ratio. 

BUT in the end windows phone (WP7) decided to do something entirely different. Couple of good links: http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/ and http://www.quirksmode.org/m/tests/widthtest.html .

In the end, on our case we just sniffed for the ipad.

Comment: I have resolved this issue with adding this piece of code for mobile devices `$('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');`
Buto for some reason this solution doesn't work on samsung mobile devices :(

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into an issue with the dpi/definition of the device, basically 1 pixel is not equal to 1 pixel.  This should be fairly easy to research.