# How to Bypass jquery media mobile view to see desktop view

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile, media-queries

i created a jquery media on my wordpress blog. When people come on my blog on mobile its show only a specific content, and when they are on desktop it shows something else.

The thing is, i want to add a "view desktop version" so it bring people to the original content. However since i have media query it bring back to mobile view.

anyway to bypass the media query once they click on desktop view ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your css code.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Show full site" button to bypass css media queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312707/show-full-site-button-to-bypass-css-media-queries)

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking into [ReViewJs](http://responsiveviewport.com/), it looks like that is being developed for the purpose of solving your kind of problem.

On a sidenote: If you need something like this you might want to rethink your design-approach. Why would this be necessary? If you really want your users to see the 'original content', why not try to incorporate that into the mobile design?